# How to exclude some specific header files from include path in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, header-files

Let's assume we have two directories dirA and dirB which contains 50 files each.

dirA - header_1.hh header_2.hh header_3.hh ---- header_50.hh

dirB - header_1.hh header_2.hh header_3.hh ----- header_50.hh

In my main.cc file, I want to include header_<1-40>.hh files from dirA, and remaining header_<41-50>.hh from dirB.

**In Makefile, I have include path as:**
INCL_PATH += -I/dirA
INCL_PATH += -I/dirB

How can I exclude 41-50 header files from getting included from path A?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the include path in the middle of a compilation unit -- there's no preprocessor directive to do that.  You best bet is probably to include the directories in the #include directives in the file:

```
#include <dirA/header_1.hh>
    :
#include <dirA/header_40.hh>
#include <dirB/header_41.hh>
    :
#include <dirB/header_50.hh>
```

Then just have your -I option specify the parent of dirA/dirB